# More columns vs. more rows to optimize storage and performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance-tuning, storage

I have a table with this structure:

```
ticker         VARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
interval       VARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
ts             TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
price          FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (ticker, interval, ts)
```

There are 40 tickers (to eventually be extended to around 130) and 8 intervals.
New rows (40 * 8) are added every 10 seconds as a bulk copy, which represents 115k rows/hour. They are written once and never modified.

Read operations are always done for fairly large time ranges (multiple of days) and request one ticker and 3 intervals for it, using this:

```
SELECT * FROM exchange.{tableName}
WHERE ticker = '{ticker}' AND \"interval\" IN ({intervalsText})
AND ts >= '{fromTime.Format}' AND ts < '{toTime.Format}'
ORDER BY ts
```

My question here is if it would be beneficial to group all the intervals in a single row per ticker. Like this:

```
ticker           VARCHAR                     NOT NULL,
ts               TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
price_interval0  FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
price_interval1  FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
...
price_interval7  FLOAT8                      NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (ticker, ts)
```

This means 8x less rows in the table, a smaller index, but each query may need to load the whole row to just return 3 values and discard 5.

I don't know how Postgres organizes the data internally and if a whole row would be retrieved at once (which is my assumption) and then parts of it get extracted, etc...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over time, that's going to be a lot of rows!

#### Basics

Yes, storing 8 `float8` in a single row will beat 8 rows with 1 `float8` each by a long shot, in storage *and* performance.
But you can do more ...

#### Table design

To **optimize storage *and* performance**:

```
CREATE TABLE ticker (
  ticker_id smallint GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, ticker text NOT NULL UNIQUE   
);

CREATE TABLE tbl (
  the_date        date     NOT NULL  -- columns in this order!
, timeslot        smallint NOT NULL
, ticker_id       smallint NOT NULL REFERENCES ticker
, price_interval0 int      NOT NULL
, price_interval1 int      NOT NULL
 ...
, price_interval7 int      NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT tbl_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ticker_id, the_date, timeslot);  -- columns in this order!
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cd873ea5ecc6481d841977ad9b68b7ff)* - including all

#### Explanation and auxiliaries

One entry every 10 seconds comes up to 6*60*24 = 8640 distinct timeslots per day. A `smallint` with its range of -2^15 to 2^15 can easily hold that.

Of course, we don't store the full ticker name every time. A smallint FK column covers 40 - 130 distinct tickers easily, and references a `ticker` table. Typically better for storage *and* performance:

- [Indexes: integer vs string performance if the number of nodes is the same](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137945/indexes-integer-vs-string-performance-if-the-number-of-nodes-is-the-same/137949#137949)

The day as `date` (4 bytes), a timeslot `smallint` (2 bytes) and a `smallint` for the ticker ID, arranged in this sequence occupy 8 bytes with no alignment padding!
Unfortunately, we cannot optimize the PK index perfectly at the same time and incur 8 bytes of alignment padding. The only stain on the storage optimization.

For convenience, you can add a `VIEW` to get pretty data:

```
CREATE VIEW tbl_pretty AS
SELECT ti.ticker, the_date + interval '10 sec' * timeslot AS ts, price_interval0, price_interval1
--   , price_interval2, ...
FROM   tbl
JOIN   ticker ti USING (ticker_id);
```

As you can see, this expression produces your original timestamp:

```
the_date + interval '10 sec' * timeslot
```

The reverse conversion will be used in the query below:

```
trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '12:34:56'))::int / 10)
```

Monetary values like a "price" shouldn't be stored as floating point number. That's a loaded foot gun. Use `numeric`. Or, since we are optimizing for storage & performance, an `integer` representing Cents typically works best. And that's only 4 bytes instead of 8 bytes for `float8`. (`numeric` depends on actual length, typically bigger). See:

- [Is it possible to insert un-formatted data for money data type in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183964/is-it-possible-to-insert-un-formatted-data-for-money-data-type-in-postgresql/183975#183975)
- [PostgreSQL: Which Datatype should be used for Currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15729573/939860)

#### Storage

This will occupy:

- (24(tuple header) + 4(item identifier) + 4 + 2 + 2 + 4*8 + 4) = **72** bytes per table row - no padding at all
  (Your original idea for the compound row would occupy (24 + 4 + (min. 8) + 8 + 8*8) = 108 bytes or more per row.)
- (8(index header) + 2 + 2(padding) + 4 + 2 + 6(padding)) = **24** bytes per PK index entry

Plus minimal overhead per 8kb data page, and no overhead for dead tuples (never updated).

Details:

- [Making sense of Postgres row sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13570853/939860)
- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2966524/939860)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

The PK index would be smaller (16 instead of 24 bytes per tuple) if we could make it on `(the_date, timeslot, ticker_id)`. But we **need** it on `(ticker_id, the_date, timeslot)` to support your query optimally. *Equality* before *range*. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)
- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)

#### Query

Your query becomes:

```
SELECT price_interval3, price_interval7  -- just the intervals you need
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ticker_id = (SELECT ticker_id FROM ticker WHERE ticker = 'ticker_3')
AND    (the_date, timeslot) >= (date '2022-04-20', trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '00:00:00'))::int / 10)
AND    (the_date, timeslot) <  (date '2022-04-20', trunc(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM time '00:01:00'))::int / 10)
ORDER  BY the_date, timeslot;
```

Or short:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ticker_id = 3
AND    (the_date, timeslot) >= ('2022-04-20', 0)
AND    (the_date, timeslot) <  ('2022-04-20', 6)
ORDER  BY the_date, timeslot;
```

Note the use of ROW value comparison! See:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982895/939860)
- [What's a good way of doing a > or < comparison that considers NULLs to be sorted first or last?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310897/whats-a-good-way-of-doing-a-or-comparison-that-considers-nulls-to-be-sorted/310938#310938)

#### Performance

This is supported ***perfectly*** by the PK index on `(ticker_id, the_date, timeslot)`. No other indexes required. You get a plan like:

```
Index Scan using tbl_pkey on tbl  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=16)
  Index Cond: ((ticker_id = 3) AND (ROW(the_date, timeslot) >= ROW('2022-04-20'::date, 0)) AND (ROW(the_date, timeslot) < ROW('2022-04-20'::date, 6)))
```